# Can't Use Custom Keywords in pvporcupine

Tags: python, string

I am trying to use a custom keyword for pvporcupine, but when I run the file I get an error saying the file can not be found.
My code looks like this:

```
import pvporcupine

ACCES_KEY = the access key I got on the pvporcupine site
KEYWORD_FILE PATH = the file path to the file that I have copied and pasted and made sure to use / instead of \

porcupine = pvporcupine.create(
     acces_key='${ACCESS_KEY}'
     keyword_paths = ['${KEYWORD_FILE_PATH}']
)

print(porcupine)
```

My error:

```
    raise IOError("Couldn't find keyword file at '%s'." % x)
OSError: Couldn't find keyword file at '${KEYWORD_FILE_PATH}'.
```

I have tried using \, r, and / in the string. I have checked multiple other stack questions and lots of google and I am out of ideas. I know printing porcupine will probably give me weird data but that is to make sure it works. What should I do?

Comment: The definition of `porcupine` isn't even valid Python syntax. If you want a `dict`, it's something like `porcupine = { 'access_key': ACCESS_KEY, 'keyword_paths': [KEYWORD_FILE_PATH]}`. What you have now looks like a mix of Python, shell, and some other syntax.

Comment: Nothing in the code shown would even attempt IO, let alone raise an `IOError`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: My bad, I put in my code wrong. Just fixed it.

Comment: It still looks like you are using shell syntax. I suspect you want `pyporcupine.create(access_key=ACCESS_KEY, keyword_paths=[KEYWORD_FILE_PATH])`.